# RelativeLayout cannot be cast to android.text.TextWatcher

Tags: java, android

I am trying to make an auto complete including an able to press the option I searched from a list that came from firebase data

---

RelativeLayout cannot be cast to android.text.TextWatcher - that's my error

```
public void autoSearch(View view) {
        //auto search complete for comunity list
        this.context = context;

        String array1[] = firebaseComunityListArr.toArray(new String[firebaseComunityListArr.size()]);
        AutoCompleteTextView txt = (AutoCompleteTextView) view.findViewById(R.id.myAutoComplete);
        txt.addTextChangedListener((TextWatcher) getView());
        txt.setAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>(getContext(), android.R.layout.simple_dropdown_item_1line, array1));
        txt.setTextColor(Color.GREEN);
        txt.setAdapter(adapter);
    }


   @Override
    public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence charSequence, int i, int i1, int i2) {

    }

    @Override
    public void onTextChanged(CharSequence charSequence, int i, int i1, int i2) {

    }

    @Override
    public void afterTextChanged(Editable editable) {

    }
```

this is the xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout  xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <AutoCompleteTextView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:inputType="textAutoComplete|textAutoCorrect"
        android:imeOptions="actionSearch"
        android:hint="search here"
        android:id="@+id/myAutoComplete"/>

    <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:id="@+id/my_recycler_view"
        />



</RelativeLayout >
```

Comment: the line txt.addTextChangedListener((TextWatcher) getView());

Comment: you have to implement the methods of textWatcher . . . why are you passing a view in addTextChangeListener()??

Comment: cus it is inside a fragment and I did implement the methods of textWatcher .. its not the problem

Comment: then post your code of implementation too

Comment: the answer given by the munir is the correct implementation you can use

Comment: Since he has implemented methods in fragment already, simply `txt.addTextChangedListener(this);` should work.

Comment: yes, this is right approach @Ranjan

Comment: @Ranjan thank you I fix it to the way u advised but still an error- the same

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per my understand you need to implement TextWatcher like this way

```
txt.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {

   @Override
   public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {}

   @Override    
   public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start,
     int count, int after) {
   }

   @Override    
   public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start,
     int before, int count) {

   }
  });
```

As you have already implement textWatcher

Change this

```
txt.addTextChangedListener((TextWatcher) getView());
```

To

```
txt.addTextChangedListener(this);
```

Updated

add `layout_below` property to your recyclerview

```
<android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:id="@+id/my_recycler_view"
        android:layout_below="@+id/myAutoComplete"/>
```

Comment: thank for your help - I did what u wrote here but is still terminated                                                                                                    I already have implement those as default  from the android studio suggested

Comment: same but now only when I pressed the screen.. I edit some more details

Comment: ok it worked but now I have another problem - plz before I close this Q - why is my AutoCompleteTextView is on background of the list?                                                                                                               I cannot commit the search cus its behind the list

Comment: @golan `layout_below` property to recyclerview. se my updated anser

Comment: thank you Munir - I am not sure if to open a new Q - my auto complete is not completing me anymore??